# Assembler code in C

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to put a assembler code into my C function.
This function purpose is to copy value stored in src address to dst address:

`void copy(int *dst, int *src);`

My actual problematic code:

```
void copy(int *dst, int *src)
{
    asm("mov %1, %2"
        : /* no output */
        : "i" (dst),
          "i" (src)
        : ""
    );  
}
```

Giving me errors:

`test.c: In function ‘copy’:`
`test.c:29: error: unknown register name ‘’ in ‘asm’`
`test.c:29: warning: asm operand 0 probably doesn’t match constraints`
`test.c:29: warning: asm operand 1 probably doesn’t match constraints`

Line 29 is this line:
`asm("mov %1, %2"`

**EDIT:**

```
asm("mov %0, %1"
    : "=m" (dst)
    : "m" (dst),
      "m" (src)
    : ""
    );
```

Now gives me:
`error: unknown register name ‘’ in ‘asm’`
I do not know what to do with the last section.

**EDIT2**

I've read that I cant mov memory->memory, I need to use registers. And also I need to use AT&T syntax so it goes like "mov src,dest". Code below compiles, but unfortunately value in address pointed by dst is 0, instead of value I put in address pointed by src.

```
asm("movl %1, %%eax \n\t"
    "movl %%eax, %0 \n\t"
    : "=m" (dst)
    : "m" (dst),
      "m" (src)
    );
```

**EDIT3**

I did it this way (changed parameters) and it works now:

```
void copy(int *dst, int *src, int n)
{
    int a = *src;
    int b = *dst;
    asm("movl   %1, %%eax\n"
        "movl   %%eax, %0\n"
        : "=m" (b)
        : "m" (a)
        );
    *src = a;
    *dst = b;    
}
```

Comment: If you move a value, you have an input and an output. And none of them are `"i"`mmediate values. A `"m"`emory object should be appropriate for both.

Comment: What architecture is this for?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: That does not look like valid assembler to me. And I know quite a lot of them.

Comment: x86_64 and GCC 4.4.3
I'll my post with an output in a while.

Comment: I added an output to my instruction, warnings are gone.
But I still have a problem with the last section. If I leave it blank, compliler says that it **expects string literal before ')' token**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
void copy(int *dst, int *src)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__(
    "movl (%0), %%eax\n" 
    "movl %%eax, (%1)\n"
    :
    : "r"(src), "r"(dst)
    : "%eax"
  );
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
mov    (%edx), %eax   ; eax = *src
mov    %eax, (%ecx)   ; *dst = eax
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an empty entry in your clobber section. You don't need that.

Try this:

```
asm("mov %0, %1"
    : "=m" (dst)
    : "m" (dst),
      "m" (src)
    /* no clobbers */
    );
```

That code is precisely equivalent to this:

```
*dst = *src
```

so I presume this is just small example?

The code compiles, but gives:

```
t.c: Assembler messages:
t.c:2: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
```

So I think your assembler instruction needs work, but the compiler syntax is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it is just a small example.
I tried your code, but compiler tells me that: "error: expected string literal before ‘)’ token". So it looks like I shouln't leave this section empty.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the colon as well; corrected. It compiles now, although that's still not a valid assembler instruction.

Comment: Thank you. I made an EDIT to main post. It compiles now, but giving wrong results.